# Handling scroll of AppBarLayout not working(ToolBar doesn't collapse)

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I am trying to collapse the toolBar + Image and stick it to a minimum height.
Its's not working, so posting my code. Any help will be appreciated.

using these below links for reference

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#expanding-and-collapsing-toolbars

http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/

below is my code for xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        <!--            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/scrollableview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and the class code is

```
public class GroupChatDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    int mutedColor = R.attr.colorPrimary;
    GroupChatDetailsAdapter groupChatDetailsAdapter;
    private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.group_details_layout);
        setup ();
    }

    private void setup () {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById (R.id.anim_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar (toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar ().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (true);

        collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById (R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle ("Test Title");

        ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.header);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (getResources (),
                R.drawable.header);

        Palette.from (bitmap).generate (new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener () {
            @SuppressWarnings ("ResourceType")
            @Override
            public void onGenerated (Palette palette) {
                mutedColor = palette.getMutedColor (R.color.primary_500);
                collapsingToolbar.setContentScrimColor (mutedColor);
                collapsingToolbar.setStatusBarScrimColor (R.color.black_trans80);
            }
        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById (R.id.scrollableview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize (true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager (this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager (layoutManager);

        List<String> listData = new ArrayList<String> ();
        int ct = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < VersionModel.data.length * 2; i++) {
            listData.add (VersionModel.data[ct]);
            ct++;
            if (ct == VersionModel.data.length) {
                ct = 0;
            }
        }
        if (groupChatDetailsAdapter == null) {
            groupChatDetailsAdapter = new GroupChatDetailsAdapter (listData);
            recyclerView.setAdapter (groupChatDetailsAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your full XML here

Comment: Full XML is posted , since the code was not formated so it was not showing 1 end tag

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but the fitSystemWindows on your CoordinatorLayout is breaking this. Put your CoordinatorLayout inside a FrameLayout (and move the fitSystemWindows=true to the FrameLayout).

Answer (score -1):

you do not need to provide `app:layout_scrollFlags` to your `ToolBar` & `ImageView` as its already set via `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Also, you can set `app:layout_collapseMode` to your ToolBar as "pin", "parallax", or "none" as per your requirement.

Also, you have not provide content of `CoordinatorLayout` just make sure your namespace defined correctly as below.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: I tried with removing layout_scrollFlags from ToolBar and ImageView and also tried shuffling between "pin", "parallax", or "none" for ToolBar's layout_collapseMode, and put xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" for CoordinatorLayout : nothing works .

Comment: My build.gradle version was having recyclerView script of 21.1.0 build, changed it to 22.2.0 and buildToolsVersion to 23.0.0. and it works. Because all those new features appeared in the 22.2.0 version of support library.